# problems installing gfortran

Tags: package-management, dependencies

When I try to sudo apt-get install gfortran, the following error message pop up, it seems that there are some broken packages, how do I fix that?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gfortran : Depends: gfortran-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a; lsb_release -a; apt-cache policy gfortran gfortran-4.8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

You can see the list of held packages by:

`apt-mark showhold`

and then un-hold them by

`sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>`

---

Solution 2:

You can also try using installing with *aptitude*

`sudo aptitude install gfortan`

If you don't have aptitude installed yet, get it with:

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

---

Solution 3:

`sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`

---

Solution 4:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Solution 5:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

Solution 6:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution solves the problem. But regarding the first solution, showhold shows nothing, what has happened to my computer?

Comment: Nope, the second solution also does not solve the problem, after aptitude gfortran, nothing is installed

Comment: This means that you don't have any packages on hold but you have some broken packages that you can try fixing by following this guide: http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/05/how-to-fix-broken-packages-using.html

Comment: still doesn't work, what can i do?

Comment: Can you send us contents of your  /etc/apt/sources.list and make it as update?

Answer (score 4):

After all combination of packages upgrade commands I have fixed this problem by installing gfortran-5 library:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gfortran-5
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install `liboctave-dev` when I ran into this issue,
tried tens of solutions and none of them actually solved my problem, no held packages, no broken packages, clean repository/cache or whatever,
until I noticed something was wrong with the `gcc`.
So basically, a newer version of `gcc` got installed and all these packages and dependent packages depend on the old one. Unlike other cases, a newer `gcc` is considered to be incompatible.
In short, this line relieved me of the pain.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1
```